# What does 1ø mean in the spec: 1ø 220V 60Hz?

Tags: mains

I'm hooking up my mini split (AC/heater) and it says the system needs 1ø 208-230V 60Hz.
What does 1ø mean in this context?

Comment: Did it come with a plug attached? A residential unit designed for residential use should just plug in. If you need to wire the plug, read the instructions carefully. If you aren't sure, ask on the home improvement *DIY* SE site, they will know better.

Comment: I know what 1ø means.  But I don't believe OP's mini split system really needs 208-230 V single phase.  They usually require 2 phase 115 VAC, which is what's in most homes (in the US, anyway).

Comment: @SteveSh 208 V single phase is what you get by connecting two live phases from a 120 V L-N three-phase system. It's not two-phase, it *is* single-phase. 2-phase would be two live phases and a neutral, if it's anything at all.

Comment: @Heath - So then isn't two live phases, 180 deg apart, and a neutral what we have in most of the US?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context it means "single phase" - see [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-phase_electric_power) for confirmation.

> In electrical engineering, single-phase electric power (abbreviated 1φ) is the distribution of alternating current electric power using a system in which all the voltages of the supply vary in unison.

Comment: Isn't this the same, at least in regards to OP's use (mini split system) as using phase A and B of a 2 phase powered home?  I don't know of any residential areas that provide single phase 230 VAC to the residence.

Comment: @SteveSh - OPs email is .fr (France).

Comment: @SteveSh Most of the world provides single phase 230 V (give or take a few volts) to the residence. A couple countries do 120 V instead, but they're the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @Mattman944 - How did you glean the OP is in France?  I see nothing in the question that hints of his location.

Comment: @SteveSh - Internet country code in their profile.  .fr = France

Comment: @Mattman944 - OK, I see it now.  Would be nicer if he just stated that in his question, which is what's encouraged on the SE Home Improvement site.

Comment: actually I'm in the USA :)    -  my drier is 230V and it has this special plug with 4 prongs (so I guess it has 2 phases), however the minisplit has just 3 entries including ground, so I didn't really understand how to have 220v with 1 phase. I looked up online and it seems that I can just use the 2 hot wires to have 220V